# Selecting all text on click even when the input is set to Read Only?

Tags: jquery

I have an input box :

```
 <input type="text" rel="autoselect" value="foo bar">
```

I'm using jquery in order to select all the text when some one click on the input :

```
 $("input[rel='autoselect']").on("click", function () {
  $(this).select();
  });
```

The code above works just fine. However, when I set the input to read only, the selection doesn't happen.

```
 <input readonly="readonly" type="text" rel="autoselect" value="foo bar">
```

Is there any way I can select all text on click without allowing users to be able to change what is inside the input box ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You need to call `.focus` EXPLICITELY as input field is `READONLY`

```
$('input[rel=autoselect]').click(function(e) {
    $(this).focus().select();  
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hAVg9/24/)